# Linear irreducible representations of residually finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Hi,
 Is it true that all irreducible unitary representations of a residually finite group are finite dimensional?

Actually I suspect that it is not, but cannot find any example.

Comment: How about the free group with two generators? Every representation of every 2-generated group is a representation of $F_2$.

Comment: Mark is right. Here is for example a nice result by Michael Cowling and Tim Steger: Let $G$ be a non-compact simple Lie group, and let $\pi$ be a unitary irreducible representation of $G$; assume that $\pi$ is not in the discrete series of $G$ (you exclude countably many rep's in a continuum). Then the restriction of $\pi$ to any lattice $\Gamma$ in $G$, is an irreducible representation of $\Gamma$.

Comment: To clarify: when you talk about an irreducible representation $\pi:G \to {\rm End}(V)$, do you mean that there is no proper $G$-invariant subspace other than zero, or do you mean that there is no proper, **closed** $G$-invariant subspace other than zero

Comment: I believe the standard definition is no closed $G$-invariant subspaces.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark Sapir pointed out, this is of course false. There are tons of infinite dimensional irreducible representations of residually finite groups. In fact, I think that any finitely generated group for which the answer is yes, is virtually abelian.

However, you could also ask whether all irreducible representations of a given residually finite group are *weakly* contained in finite dimensional representations. This is true for $\mathbb F_2$ but for example not for $SL(3,\mathbb Z)$. For the group $\mathbb F_2 \times \mathbb F_2$, this problem is open and equivalent to Connes Embedding problem.

Comment: @ Andreas: Correct, the assumption in the OP ("every unitary irrep is finite dimension") implies that the group is type I, so by Thoma's theorem the group is virtually abelian.

Your sentence "You could ask...", ending with a (in)famous open question, is a bit tough (:-).

Comment: Rats! I was going to say that!